# Force Desktop Site on Varnish

Tags: magento, varnish, varnish-vcl

I used varnish to redirect mobile agents to mobile site:

```
sub vcl_recv {

if (req.http.user-agent ~ "iP(hone|od)|android|(?i)^samsung|(?i)android|(?i)android 3") {

error 750 "Moved Temporarily";

}

}

sub vcl_error {

if (obj.status == 750) {

set obj.http.Location = "http://m.website.com" + req.url;

set obj.status = 301;

return(deliver);

}
}
```

By the way, on mobile site we have the  url:

http://www.website.com/?mredirect=yes

Is there any way to force mobile agents to desktop version? It means have url will work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

add a cookie (in your website) and than check in varnish VCL:

```
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "redirua=0")  // the cookie for "do not redir by UA"
    {       set req.http.X-RedirUA = 0;
            set req.http.BrowserType = "BrowserTypePC";
            set req.http.SkipUA=1;}
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "redirua=1")
    {        set req.http.X-RedirUA = 1;}
```

in your server and in `vcl_hash`  you need to check this header, and than UNSET for cache usage.